Slowness in WritePrivateProfileString and GetPrivateProfileString APIs in Windows 11 Compared to Windows 10
I am experiencing a noticeable performance degradation when using the WritePrivateProfileString and GetPrivateProfileString APIs in a Windows desktop application after upgrading to Windows 11. The same application performs significantly faster on Windows 10 with the same hardware and environment.
Here are some key details:

On Windows 10, both the write and read operations for .ini files are very quick (usually completing in under 1ms for individual call).
On Windows 11, the same operations take noticeably longer, sometimes up to 2-3ms or more (for individual call)

Code snippet for writing to an .ini file and measure the time for writing:
Here I used a for loop to call the API 10000 times over.
CString filePath = L"C:\\path\\to\\myfile.ini";
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   section.Format(L"Settings%d", i);
   key.Format(L"Volume%d", i);
   value.Format(L"%d", i);
   WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, filePath);
}
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;

The result in
Windows 10 : 7.93 s
Windows 11 : 12.609 s
Code snippet for reading from an .ini file:
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   section.Format(L"Settings%d", i);
   key.Format(L"Volume%d", i);
   TCHAR buffer[256];
   GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, L"Default", buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(TCHAR), filePath);
}
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;

The result in
Windows 10 : 6.72 s
Windows 11 : 10.46 s

Verified that the file paths and .ini files are valid and accessible.
Ran the application with administrator privileges to avoid any potential permission issues.
Measured the time using std::chrono to ensure accurate time reporting.

Environment:

Windows 10: Version 22H2
Windows 11: Version 23H2
Hardware: Same hardware configuration for both operating systems.
Development Environment: Visual Studio 2017, C++.


Can you look in hex viewer (e.g. Lister form Total Commander) if Windows 11 ini file starts with FF FE or EF BB BF.?

These APIs have been deprecated for decades. Does this performance degradation cause an actual problem or is it just a simple curiosity?

Hard to believe that anybody would contemplate actually calling these apis in 2024

If you write/read 10000 entries into/from an .ini file, you're doing something wrong anyway.

@Luke actually they are not deprecated (in a way they won't be removed) but they are (awfull) out of date , they are there since Windows 3.x initialization files.
